# how to run this piece of sql code in oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, isql

I have this code in sql, it runs perfectly on sql server 2005. But when i run this code in isql plus, it gives error, what changes should I make to run it.

code is---

```
DECLARE @stu_Name VARCHAR(50), @stu_Address VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @stu_Name = g.stu_Name,@stu_Address= g.stu_address 
FROM student as g
WHERE unique_no = 's121' 
INSERT INTO 
   dbo.student(stu_no, stu_name, dateofbirth,stu_unique_no, stu_name,stu_address)
VALUES
     (13, 'John', '1990-12-12','s121', @stu_Name, @stu_Address);
```

Comment: Please go read about PL/SQL (get a book, read the Oracle docs). The syntax is very different from MS SQL syntax.

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following: 
begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>

Comment: m getting this error . i am trying to learn. But to do this to a single peice of code . i have to learn complete oracle.

Comment: In future please use the documentation to answer these lame syntax questions rather than flooding SO with them.  I've linked to the relevant section in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@A.B.Cade gives [the efficient way of doing things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558003/146325).  Of course, his syntax would have worked in SQL Server too.  So preseumably the object of the exercise is to exactly translate the T-SQL into PL/SQL.

```
DECLARE 
    l_stu_Name. student.stu_Name%type;
    l_stu_Address student student.stu_address%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT stu_Name, stu_Address
    into  l_stu_Name, l_stu_address 
    FROM student as g
    WHERE unique_no = 's121' ;
    INSERT INTO 
       dbo.student(stu_no, stu_name, dateofbirth,stu_unique_no, stu_name,stu_address)
    VALUES
         (13, 'John', '1990-12-12','s121', l_stu_Name, l_stu_Address);
END;
/
```

You should know that the Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free.  You should learn to navigate it.  [find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#BABGEDAE). questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO 
   dbo.student(stu_no, stu_name, dateofbirth,stu_unique_no, stu_name,stu_address)
SELECT 13, 'John', to_date('1990-12-12','yyyy-mm-dd'),g.unique_no, g.stu_Name, g.stu_address
FROM student as g
WHERE unique_no = 's121';
```

didn't check it but this is a start...